# CSS submenu hover

Tags: css, menu, submenu

I have following menu:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="menu1.php">Menu 1</a></li>    
<li><a href="menu2.php">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="menu21.php">Menu 2 - 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="menu22.php">Menu 2 - 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="menu3.php">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="menu31.php">Menu 3 - 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="menu32.php">Menu 3 - 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="menu33.php">Menu 3 - 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="menu4.php">Menu 4</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="menu41.php">Menu 4 - 1</a></li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

[image with result](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2n0v3uq.jpg)

- On page menu1.php i need to see - image 1
- On page menu1.php on hover effect on Menu 2 - image 2
- On page menu2.php - image 2
- On page menu21.php - image 2

So on page i need to see this page submenu and with mouse on other links change this submenu to submenu of the page, on which is the mouse.

Hope it's understandable.

Comment: In order for anyone to be able to help, you need to show what you've tried. No one's just going to write code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

the main idea would be to assign each of your 'li' elements a class, and do the following:

```
.classForLi1
{
  /*some properties for the menu*/
}

.classForLi1:hover
{
  /*some properties for the menu when hovered */
}
```

and the same for the other menus.

if you want a more specific answer, please try to solve this on your own first and tell us where you got stuck.like apohl wrote we will help you solve an issue, but not write the whole code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm7Ct/6/)

([alternative sub menu style](http://jsfiddle.net/fm7Ct/7/))

The below will give you a starting point to do the menu itself, you can then e.g. set inline styles to `display:block;` on the sub menu `ul` element you wish displayed on one of your given .php pages.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu 1
        <ul>
            <li>Menu 1-1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 2
        <ul>
            <li>Menu 2-1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:arial;
    width:100%;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
    background:#2E94C7;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
}
}
body ul li {
    position:relative;
}
ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    margin:10px 0 0 -10px;
}
ul li ul li {
    display:block;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```